# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__SECRET_DOM_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get

> Uncaught TypeError occurs (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> '__SECRET_DOM_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED' of undefined)

when I am using React JS

```html
<script src="res/build/react-min.js"></script>
<script src="res/build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But when I use this - `<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.3.min.js"></script>`, everything works correctly. Both contain the same scripts.

Comment: Explanation of the message... https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/3nhk5e/secret_dom_do_not_use_or_you_will_be_fired/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error is thrown because the react-dom cannot find an instance of React. I suppose this has something to do with the fact you are using `res/build/react-min.js` instead of `res/build/react.min.js`

Kudos for the function name in the react-dom tho:

```
(function(React) {
  return React.__SECRET_DOM_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED;
});
```